# UIWebView and local storage

Tags: ios, webkit, local-storage

How  I can use webView local storage  ?
I try this:

```
  WebPreferences* prefs = [webView preferences];
  [prefs _setLocalStorageDatabasePath:@"~/Library/Application Support/MyApp"];
  [prefs setLocalStorageEnabled:YES];
```

but in new IOS sdk (xcode 4.3.2) i dont have WebKit.framework

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In new sdk webView has defaul cache (tnx HTML5 =) )... so all you need is include cache in your HTML

Comment: how about a sample of this unrewa?

Comment: @JoeHealy you need import it in your html page read more on http://www.opencms-wiki.org/wiki/HTML5_offline_cache_manifest